# Finding all differentiable functions satisfying a property

Tags: calculus, functions

I am trying to find all differentiable functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{+},
f'(x)=\frac{f(x+n)-f(x)}{n}$$
I know that a sufficient class of functions with this property is all linear functions $f(x)=ax+b$ for some real constants $a$ and $b$ since
$$f'(x)=a=\frac{a(x+n)+b-(ax+b)}{n}=\frac{f(x+n)-f(x)}{n}$$
but what is the necessary class of functions with the property?

Comment: I think this was a Putnam problem some years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$, it follows that $f'$ is differentiable as well, with
\begin{align} f''(x) = f'(x+1)-f'(x) &= (f(x+2)-f(x+1)) - (f(x+1)-f(x)) \\
&= f(x+2)-2f(x+1)+f(x) \\
&= (f(x+2)-f(x)) - 2(f(x+1)-f(x)) \\
&= 2f'(x) - 2f'(x) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Hence, $f'$ must be constant, i.e. $f$ must be linear.

Comment: @Sil The assumptions say $f'(x)=\frac{f(x+n)-f(x)}{n}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Oh I see, should have read the question. Thanks